# is there's a better way than saving user data in session?

Tags: django, postgresql, session

When the user register and he enter his phone number, i don't save the data into the database untill the user verify his phone number by entering the code sent to his phone (OTP)
the problem is that i save this data in the session untill he enter the OTP, then i save it into the DB

is there's a better way? As it's not safe to save the user password in the session

i thought about saving directly in the DB and i will use Corns.py to check every day if there's any user didn't verify his phone number, then it will delete it..
i also thought about saving normal info in the session like name, phone number, email, then i'll send him the OTP and after, he will continue registeration and he will type his password and it will be saved in the DB directly
But i still think that there's a better solution
what can it be?

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved in several ways

1-Cache the data in Redis and delete cache data when verify otp

2-When registering the user,set is_active=False and save it,When you have verified the otp set is_active=True

3- if you use DRF,front end can save data in local storage and give you the data later

4- Saving data in the session does not cause any problems if you use it after verification and delete it.